# How will MRKT work with Unity XR Interaction toolkit?

Tags: mrtk

The keynote at Unite Copenhagen revealed an upcoming "XR Interaction toolkit". Will this be kept seperate from or integrated into MRKT?

Answer (score 0):

MRTK will be investigating and evaluating Unity's announced features. Once we have more information, we will open GitHub issues to track any required work.